# SSL difference between Azure Function .Net 3.1 to .Net 5

Tags: c#, .net, azure, apache-kafka, azure-functions

I had an Azure Function that was triggered by Kafka (Cloud Confluent Kafka) and it used to run in .Net Core 3.1. It used the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka` NuGet.

Now I have to switch it into an isolated .Net 5 Azure Function and I use the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Kafka` NuGet.

The problem is that now, I keep receiving an SSL error message:

```
Libkafka: [thrd:sasl_ssl://xxx-xxx.xxx.azure.confluent.cloud:9092/bootstra]: sasl_ssl://xxx-xxx.xxx.azure.confluent.cloud:9092/bootstrap: SSL handshake failed: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed: broker certificate could not be verified, verify that ssl.ca.location is correctly configured or root CA certificates are installed (add broker's CA certificate to the Windows Root certificate store) (after 19ms in state CONNECT, 158 identical error(s) suppressed)
```

I wonder how should I re-configure the function so it would have the certificates? And why is it different from the .net core version which I didn't have to do anything special in order to receive a successful handshake

Comment: Facing the same issue, where you able yo solve it?